# Obtener los minutos de un decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
    SELECT SUM([Horas Vuelo]) / 60 AS Horas  , SUM([Horas Vuelo]) FROM ER.FactExperienciaRed
WHERE IdFecha BETWEEN 20190101 AND 20190131 AND IdEstatus NOT IN(1,2)
```

Que me da como resultado 2569.8 y 154188, el primer resultado en horas y el segundo en minutos. Pero resulta que de el primero quiero concertir el decimal a minutos lo que vendría siendo 2569.48. ¿Como hago esto para calcularlo automaticamente? Tengo el mismo problema en un modelo de SSAS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para convertir los decimales a minutos.

Sucede algo muy extraño, ya lo realice en SQL y funciona perfectamente. Pero si trato de replicar lo mismo en MDX me muestra decimales arriba de 60 y obviamente no debería de suceder.

```
VBA!Round([Measures].[Horas Vuelo]/60) + ([Measures].[Horas Vuelo]/60 -
VBA!Round([Measures].[Horas Vuelo]/60)) * 60 / 100
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Guillermo Ricardo Spindola Bri:

Dado que tu consulta de suma de horas retornará siempre algún valor, puedes aplicar lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @table_horas TABLE(horas DECIMAL(10, 2));

INSERT INTO @table_horas(horas)
VALUES
(2569.0),
(2569.1),
(2569.2),
(2569.3),
(2569.4),
(2569.5),
(2569.6),
(2569.7),
(2569.8),
(2569.9),
(2570.0);
```

Con la tabla cargada, como ejemplo.

```
SELECT t.horas as original, CAST(FLOOR(t.horas) + (t.horas - FLOOR(t.horas)) * 60 /  100 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) as resultado  
FROM 
     @table_horas t;
```

[image: Resultados]

Answer (score 0):

Dejo un par de cálculos para obtener minutos y segundos. Primero obtengo la parte decimal restando la parte entera usando ROUND para truncar (por eso uso el tercer parámetro). No uso FLOOR por su comportamiento con los valores negativos. Después uso ese valor para multiplicar por el número de minutos o segundos en una hora y luego dividir entre 60 para obtener el resultado (minutos) y el residuo (segundos).

```
SELECT MinutosDecimales = (Horas - ROUND(Horas, 0, 1)) * 60 ,
       MinutosEnteros   = CAST( (Horas - ROUND(Horas, 0, 1)) * 3600 AS int) / 60,
       SegundosEnteros  = CAST( (Horas - ROUND(Horas, 0, 1)) * 3600 AS int) % 60
FROM (SELECT 2569.8 AS Horas UNION ALL
      SELECT 2648.91666 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2656.9)x
```